# importing excel to database c# asp.net

Tags: c#, excel, database, import

so let me tell you first that im a first year programmer so dont expect much ;)

This school year is different to me. I am doing a intership at a company. I have a got a assignement but i dont have a clue how to start. My assignement is 'The user fills in a excel template. That template must be imported to a database using c# asp.net' i never worked with asp and a little with c#.

I have problems with :
1. opening a file stream with asp.net (So i can pick a file)
2. Reading the excel file
3 importing it to a db

sorry if something is unclear. Please ask.

kind regards

Comment: Welcome to SO.. A heads up about the sort of questions we answer here - ones that have a simple fact based answer that could ideally be expressed (ignoring code samples, long discourse on the *why* and *how* aspects of a question and other appendix type things) in at most 5 lines. If it would take an expert longer than 5 lines to answer the direct question you asked, then it's an indication your question is too broad. We also have rules that exclude questions that incite discussion/debate about the "best" way to do things, or recommend X over Y, as this ultimately produces argument.

Comment: Thank you for answering :). Can you help me with opening a excel file ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464902/how-to-open-an-excel-file-in-c

but your question is poorly written. You should always:
Show your input and expected output.
Show us what you have already tried, this isn't a code writing service. 
Clear information about errors you encounter. 
Enough code example to reproduce the error when possible. 

You don't have a coding error, you have an architecture issue.

Comment: "How do I open an excel file in c#?" -> one way is to use EPPlus: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897697/opening-excel-document-using-epplus - EPPlus is a library that reads and writes XLSX files. You do not need to have excel installed. This is kinda also a question that could incite debate, because here i'm recommending a particular library. The reason why the linked question survived is because the poster made the decision to use EPPlus on his own, and had some trouble, and we helped with the trouble (so we weren't asked to recommend or provide code for using a library)

Comment: Also, comments aren't answers and are not used for answering. On questions they're use to clarify and ask for additional details, or to guide a next set of steps. On answers theyre typically used to suggest errors or improvements, deviations from the process etc. My comment above is a question/answer pair and shouldnt really stand, but seeing yorue a new user, I'm aiming to guide you in how to effectively use SO (i.e. dont ask that). Other people are way more hardline than me and will simply downvote/close your question. Don't take it personally (it's hard not to).. I still get DV/closed :)